# Flutter: Read variables passed to build_runner in the build.yaml file

Tags: flutter, dart, code-generation, build-runner

Is there a way to pass a variable (like a path to the build.yaml file to then have a builder run only on a single file/directory?

```
targets:
  $default:
    builders:
      freezed:
        enabled: true
        generate_for:
          include:
            - <my/path.dart>
```

and my calling command should be something like:

```
flutter pub run build_runner -flag="my/path.dart"
```

PS: If I could then apply some ternary check if the flag is null and default to a different directory, that would be amazing :D

Comment: Perhaps you could provide more detail on what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

i think its by --define as in --help indicates.